# remove quotes from string in php

Tags: php, mysql

**Original code below works**

```
if (!Membership::is_valid([1,2,4]))Url::redirect("/accessDenied.php");
```

**The code below does not work**

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "Select allowedGroups from permissionTable WHERE 
fileName= 'myFile.php'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (!Membership::is_valid($row))Url::redirect("/accessDenied.php");
```

The field allowedGroups is a text field which contains 1,2,4. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What 'allowedGroups' field contains? Is digits separated by comma like 1,2,4 ?

Comment: Well you can't just put square brackets around a string and expect PHP to convert the string magically to the desired array. Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: @Chudilka Yes. The field allowedGroups' contains digits separated by comma like 1,2,4

Comment: @simon, explode did the trick. thanks